# Node.js server uploading on Cpanel not working

Tags: node.js, cpanel, vps

I wanted to deploy my node.js server on Cpanel,
my company give me subdomain access to practice that deployment,
I have successfully set up the node application and added the required files etc.. but
only the initial route "/" is working none other than that is working
I have used Express for routing
what are the possible issues I can't able to file

I have tried all tutorials explaining how to set it up but none of them perform express routing

Answer (score 0):

after multiple research on it i finally figure it out that it's all about .htaccess file and the default PORT 60000 (this PORT is must to use)

.htaccess file

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/nodetestcp/career"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/nodetestcp/nodevenv/career/12/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile app.js
PassengerAppLogFile "/home/nodetestcp/bugs/errors.log"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:60000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAMEJ !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAHE) I-d
RewriteRule ^(.")$ http://127.0.0.1:60000/$1 [P,L]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```